# Creating a dictionary from DataFrame column and values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
     A     B     C      D
0    One   Two   Three  Four
1    31    47    44     22
2    53    38    11     27
3    86    84    81     87
4    57    4     23     46
```

I want to create a loop that will give me key of one, two, three, with values of 53, 47, 44, 22 going  down. So first dict would be

```
 {'One': 31, 'Two': 47, 'Three': 44, 'Four' : 22}
```

next one

```
{'One': 53, 'Two': 38, 'Three': 11, 'Four' : 22}
```

and so on.

I have completly no clue how to accomplish it. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. As an aside, wouldn't it make more sense to add the values in the first row to the header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DataFrame.to_dict() in order to accomplish it.

You can find more about the topic on:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html